# Конвертирование клавиш в ToUnicodeEx

Tags: c#

Как конвертировать клавиатурных хук который сможет понимать все клавиши и выводить нужный символ?!

Используя класс: **UserActive**

**Shell.Text** - Это "textBox".

Я вывожу нужный мне символ таким способом:

```
public void keydown(KeyboardHook.VKeys key)
        {
            if (InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage.Culture.ToString() == "ru-RU")
            {
                if (key == KeyboardHook.VKeys.KEY_A)
                {
                    Shell.Text += "ф";
                }
                else if (key == KeyboardHook.VKeys.KEY_B)
                {
                    Shell.Text += "и";
                }
                else if (key == KeyboardHook.VKeys.SPACE)
                {
                    Shell.Text += " ";
                }
                else if (key == KeyboardHook.VKeys.KEY_Q)
                {
                    Shell.Text += "й";
                }
      }
```

и.т.д

Чтобы не использовать `if else` я думаю может сделать через `case switch`?, подскажите чтобы не писать такой длинный код как можно сократить, и как конвертировать в `TounicodeEx?` на примере моего кода...

Вот ссылка на классы которые использовались: [Hooks](http://rgho.st/6b6vyFN5T)

Comment: Это какой-то фреймворк? В стандартной библиотеке я не нашёл таких классов.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/370754/